# GMail API using Python Google API Client: error 400, failed precondition

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to access our GSuite GMail API using [Google API Python Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/README.md) with service account authentication. According to the docs, my MCVE code is as follows:

```
import os
import sys
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

email = sys.argv[1]

cred = Credentials.from_service_account_file(os.getenv('SERVICE_ACCOUNT'))
cred = cred.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels'])
cred.refresh(Request())

gmail = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=cred)
try:
    print(gmail.users().labels().list(userId=email).execute())
except Exception as ex:
    print('Error:', ex.content.decode('ascii'))
```

The output is:

```
Error: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "failedPrecondition",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

The usual suspects:

- The service account is granted the domain-wide delegation
- The requested email exists
- The client scopes are configured in "Admin > Security > Advanced > Manage API client access"

[image: access settings]

Another observation: when I access the API, the usage counter increases for the service account, but remains 0 for the corresponding OAuth2 client.

What else can I be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What was missing, is one little piece mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests). In addition to setting the scopes, I need to impersonate a user account by calling [`with_subject`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.with_subject):

```
cred = cred.with_subject(email)
```

After that it works as expected, hope that helps someone.